# python issues with csv

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

I just started leaning python while taking an udacity course for data analytics, and am having problems with my code in pyCharm. To preface this, the code works when used in the udacity shell and the file locations changed to instructed location for the udacity website. Below is the code and the 2 errors I'm getting. I do know C++ and thought python would be a breeze to learn kind of on the fly, but except for the coding itself I tend to get these types of errors I never encountered before. If there are any rules of thumb how to avoid this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv

daily_engagements = []
project_submissions = []

with open(r'C:\Users\austi\Downloads\daily_engagement.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    daily_engagement = list(reader)
print(project_submissions[5])

with open(r'C:\Users\austi\Downloads\project_submissions.csv', 'rt') as g:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(g)
    project_submissions = list(reader)
print(daily_engagement[17])
```

ERROR 1

```
   C:\Users\austi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe  
           C:/Users/austi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/p2prac.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/austi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/p2prac.py", line 15, in    <module>
    project_submissions = list(reader)
  File "C:\Users\austi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35- 32\lib\csv.py", line 110, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

ERROR 2

```
C:\Users\austi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe   
C:/Users/austi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/p2prac.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/austi/PycharmProjects/untitled2/p2prac.py", line 10, in  <module>
    print(project_submissions[5])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Also I aploigize if something that could fix this has been covered I looked at as many post I could find tried some fixes, and still not working

Answer (score 1):

I'll note your errors with inline comments. Basically, you seem to have trouble keeping track of objects and their names.

```
import csv

daily_engagements = [] # this is never used
project_submissions = [] # you never add anything to this list

with open(r'C:\Users\austi\Downloads\daily_engagement.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    daily_engagement = list(reader)
print(project_submissions[5]) # you've never added to this list, so it has no element 5... did you mean to use daily_engagement?

with open(r'C:\Users\austi\Downloads\project_submissions.csv', 'rt') as g:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(g)
    project_submissions = list(reader) # you are using reader, which was closed already, rather than reader1
print(daily_engagement[17])
```

Here is a cleaned-up version. I don't have your files and I don't know which data you want to print, but this is probably what you want as far as I can determine:

```
import csv

with open(r'C:\Users\austi\Downloads\daily_engagement.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    daily_engagement = list(reader)
print(daily_engagement[5])

with open(r'C:\Users\austi\Downloads\project_submissions.csv') as g:
    reader = csv.DictReader(g)
    project_submissions = list(reader)
print(project_submissions[17])
```

Comment: wow, these are simple errors, thank you for pointing out that I switched the list, and the reader erorr. This fixed it. Sorry for wasting time/space asking this